# How to track user names and file content modifications with change tracking Azure Service using KOL query

Tags: azure, change-tracking

I am tracking the changes of the file content modfied in azure vm using the Change tracking service. i scuessfully created and validated the changes it was working fine but when i try to print the user and file content modified i am stucked to get thoose details KQL query

I tried the following query But that querie retrives

ConfigurationChange
| where ConfigChangeType == "Files"
| sort by TimeGenerated asc
| project Computer, Name, ChangeCategory, PreviousSize, Size, DateModified, FileSystemPath,FieldsChanged, FileContentChecksum, Attributes

and i also tried the following also
[image: Getting Erorr while usig the WVDConnections]

Could anyone help me modify this query to include the user name and file name? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

*To include the username, you can directly execute the below query.*

```
WVDManagement | project userName
```

[image]

It retrieves all of the information about the desktop virtualization management activity.

*Or*

you can add the username attribute to the configuration change tracking table as shown.

```
ConfigurationChange 
| where ConfigChangeType == "Files" 
| sort by TimeGenerated asc 
| project Computer, Name, ChangeCategory, PreviousSize, Size, DateModified, FileSystemPath,FieldsChanged, FileContentChecksum, Attributes, UserName
```

*Error:* Failed to resolve table WVDconnections.

You must enable the diagnostic settings for the host pools in Azure virtual desktop before it can retrieve the logs and display the WVD connections table.

Refer [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-desktop/diagnostics-log-analytics) to configure the diagnostic settings for the logs and link to log analytics workspace.

Alternatively, You can use inner join after the configuration change table as shown to get the session related details.

```
ConfigurationChange 
.....#code query
| join kind=inner 
(WVDConnections 
| project SessionUserName, SessionHostName, Computer ) on Computer
```

Refer [Github](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/automation/change-tracking/manage-change-tracking.md) for more relevant information.